# Failing in codechef IDE, but working in my IDE

Tags: java

Recently I started to learn Java, so I know very little. Can anybody clear the following confusion for me?

Here is a very basic problem from CodeChef:

> Write a program that accepts a number, n, and outputs the same.

Here's my simple code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner hi = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = hi.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

If I run it in CodeChef IDE, I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

If I run the same code in my IntelliJ IDE, it works perfectly fine. Why does it happen like this? And how can I avoid it?

Comment: While I know IntelliJ is a good IDE for beginners and professional developers, I have no idea what CodeChef is. I'm inclined to blame CodeChef for running your code in an unexpected way or giving your program some sort of weird input. Try printing out what it gives you on `System.in` as-is to make sure it looks the way you expect it to.

Comment: I just fired up CodeChef and gave your code a try.  I first tried running it without putting anything in the "Input" text box.  I got the same error you are reporting.  Then I typed "100\n" onto the Input text box, and your code ran just fine.  So with CodeChef, you need to give it your input up front, before you run your program.  My guess is that you aren't doing this, but are rather expecting CodeChef to give you a prompt at which you can enter input, like in IntelliJ.  CodeChef doesn't work this way.  You need to give it your input ahead of time.

Comment: Likely CodeChef doesn't have standard input open, or the standard input was an empty file, so there is nothing (more) to read.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I had that same thought.  But if you haven't read my comment, check it out.  CodeChef does support reading input from `stdin`.  You just have to specify that input ahead of time, as CodeChef has no notion of  prompting the user for input during program execution.

Comment: @CryptoFool Thanks for your reply. I still have one problem. The thing is, I can't manually give input to the system. This problem has number of test cases and the system uses those test cases to verify whether my code is working or not. So, the input side is managed by computer. Can i tweak my code to achieve the same result as you mentioned?(There is a Custom input option, but i want my code to pass those default test cases)